# Woocommerce - Order Review total on checkout page not refreshing

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

After changing the shipping method on the Checkout page of my Woocommerce store, the total price does not update to reflect the new shipping cost.

I disabled all plugins, checked for errors, but everything is running like it should - except the total won't update.

I can't find anything about this on Google either. Anyone know what would cause this, or what steps I need to take to fix?

Comment: Are you willing to share a link to the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and it was caused by outdated custom woocommerce template files.

For example, the `review-order.php` file in `themes/my-theme/woocommerce/` was outdated and it included some of my own code.
I updated the version of that file, brought my custom code over and voila, upon changing shipping methods it successfully makes an AJAX call and refreshes the order totals.

Comment: This worked for me. All that i had changed was the class of an element. If you ever run into problems with any of woocommerce try using the original template file to see if the functionality is restored.

Answer (score 0):

In your case problem with html classes. When editing the `checkout/review-order.php` file, you need to keep the right html class `shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table` at the highest parent node. The file should look something like this:

```
<div class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <?php //do stuff, add or remove anything you want ?>
</div>
```